# .NET, get memory used to hold struct instance

Tags: c#

It's possible to determine memory usage (according to Jon Skeet's blog)
like this :

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var before = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        var point = new Point(1, 0);

        var after = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        Console.WriteLine("Memory used: {0} bytes", after - before);
    }

    #region Nested type: Point

    private class Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It prints `Memory used: 16 bytes` (I'm running x64 machine).
Consider we change Point declaration from class to struct. How then to determine memory used? Is is possible at all? I was unable to find anything about getting stack size in .NET

### **P.S**

Yes, when changed to 'struct', Point instances will *often* be stored on Stack(not always), instead of Heap.Sorry for not posting it first time together with the question.

### **P.P.S**

This situation has no practical usage at all(IMHO), It's just interesting for me whether it is possible to get Stack(short term storage) size. I was unable to find any info about it, so asked you, SO experts).

Comment: What happens when you tried it?

Comment: What would be the problem of using the same code and changing it to struct? AFAIK structs work the same way except that are treated as value types and should only be used for objects smaller than 16 bytes.

Comment: Actually, you answered your question :) Structs are often(not always value types are stored in stack, see Eric Lippert's blog)  stored in stack, code above reads available memory from heap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see a change in GetTotalMemory if you create the struct the way you did, since it's going to be part of the thread's stack, and not allocated separately.  The `GetTotalMemory` call will still work, and show you the total allocation size of your process, but the struct will not cause new memory to be allocated.

You can use [sizeof(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx) to return the size of a struct (in this case, 8 bytes).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear,I thought it is obvious, the question is - is it possible to determine memory allocated on stack at some moment :)?

Comment: @taras.roshko: You can use "dumpbin /HEADERS theProgram.exe" to see the stack size set for the program for default threads.  Look for something like "100000 size of stack reserve".  This will be the stack size used for new threads *by default*.  This can be changed at runtime for new threads via: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is special CPU register, [ESP](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Stack/S77_0040_esp_register.htm), that contains pointer to the top of the stack. Probably you can find a way to read this register from .Net (using some unsafe or external code). Then just compare value of this pointer at given moment with value at thread start - and difference between them will be more or less acurate amount of memory, used for thread's stack. Not sure if it really works, just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

In isolation, as you have done here, you might have a "reasonable" amount of success with this methodology. I am not confident the information is useful, but running this methodology, especially if you run it numerous times to ensure you did not have any other piece of code or GC action affecting the outcome. Utilizing this methodology in a real world application is less likely to give accurate results, however, as there are too many variables.

But realize, this only "reasonable" and not a surety.

Why do you need to know the size of objects? Just curious, as knowing the business reason may lead to other alternatives.

Comment: It is just for fun :). But I think, it may be useful in some memory/performance tests, comparing value/reference types (yet again))